# automating creating youtube playlist and adding filtered videos using bot

Tags: node.js

is there a youtube API that can assit to add **scraped** videos URl to a Youtube playlist using a BOT

```
    import { url } from "inspector";
    import { Context, Telegraf } from "telegraf";
    import { getFilters, Item } from "ytsr";
    import { toTitleCase } from "./helpers";
    import { SearchResult } from "./interface";
    import { youtubeSearch } from "./ytsr";
    require("dotenv").config();

     if (!process.env.BOT_TOKEN) {
         throw new Error("BOT_TOKEN must be in your .env");
}

    const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN!);

    bot.on("text", async (ctx: Context) => {
    const text: string = ctx.message?.text
       ? ctx.message?.text
       : ctx.update.message?.text || "";

        console.log("user msg:", text);

       let details = text.split(",");
       details = details.map((item: string) => {
           return item.trim();
         });
        details = details.filter(Boolean);

        console.log(details);
        let searchString = details[0];
        let type = toTitleCase(details[1] || "");
        let feature = details[2];
        let duration = details[3];
        let sortBy = details[4];

          let searchResults = await youtubeSearch(
         searchString,
         type,
        feature,
        duration
         );
        console.log("Our videos ", searchResults);

  /*
  searchResults?.items.forEach((item: Item, index: number) => {
    console.log("res:", item.type);
    let message = "";
    if (item.type == "playlist") {
      message = `Title: ${item.title}`;
      message += `\nUrl: ${item.url}`;
      message += `\nLength: ${item.length}`;
    } else if (item.type == "video") {
      message = `Title: ${item.title}`;
      message += `\nUrl: ${item.url}`;
      message += `\nDuration: ${item.duration}`;
      message += `\nIs Live: ${item.isLive}`;
      message += `\nViews: ${item.views}`;
    }
*/
         return ctx.reply(searchResults!);
        }

      module.exports = function(robot: { logger: { warning: (arg0: string) => void; }; }) 
        {
      // OAUTH...
      if (process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_API_KEY == null) {
      robot.logger.warning("Need GOOGLE_OAUTH2_API_KEY");
      return;
       }
     if (process.env.GOOGLE_OAUTH2_API_SECRET == null) {
     robot.logger.warning("Need GOOGLE_OAUTH2_API_SECRET");
     return;
     }
    };
    export { bot };
```

what i have done here is to scrape youtube url on telegram using a bot, after searching a keyword, the results should be filtered through categories such as videos,Features,duration,relevance the end results is a scraped filtred data only the url containing that data is obtained is there a way we can insert the urls into the playlist automatically thus creating a playlist, without needing of me adding videos manualy by hand to create the playlist